# Besides Prophets and Pah Wraiths, do distinct energy species ever meet in the same episode?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-eu

In at least one episode of DS9, the Prophets and Pah Wraiths meet, albeit in humanoid form. I'm curious whether there's another episode of Star Trek in which distinct energy species are involved. Obviously, there are hundreds of episodes in which distinct organic species are involved, but it seems that it's typically only one energy being per episode, maximum.

If nothing in the canon presents itself, what in non-canon does?

Comment: Actually, in "Deja Q," two Q's (at the end of the episode) and the Calamarain appear, but I'm not sure if the Calamarain are considered an energy species.

Comment: It's happened in novels numerous times. The meeting of Q and 0 immediately springs to mind. I do not recall it ever happening in a televised episode though. At least, not when the energy beings are different species; more than one Q has appeared in the same place at the same time, as you yourself say.

Comment: What if they weren't non-corporeal beings at the same time?

Comment: What about the "Sargon" episode of TOS? Didn't two people become vessels for the energy beings? And I think the Pah Wraiths and the Prophets are the same species, just on different sides.

Comment: @T-1000 They are, and that is an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Within the main canon of Star Trek (TV shows + films), there are very few instances of two *different* energy beings meeting each other

- In [Voy: Cathexis](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Cathexis_(episode)), a disembodied Chakotay defends Voyager against incorporeal baddies known as the [Komar](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Komar)
- In [TNG : Deja Q](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Deja_Q_%28episode%29), Q brings a Calamarain cloud on board his shuttle.

[image]

---

Update : Within the new IDW comic series ("[The Q Gambit, Part 6](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Q_Gambit,_Part_6)") Q meets both Pah Wraiths and Prophets

[image]

---

Within the EU novels, energy beings meet on more occasions than can be easily counted.

Just to take Q as an example;

- [Q-Squared](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Q-Squared) - Q encounters an energy being known as Redjac
- [Q-Zone](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Q-Strike) - Q encounters multiple energy beings; [Gorgan](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Gorgan), [The One](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_One) and [(*)](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/(*))
- [The Human Factor](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Human_Factor_(short_story)) - Q is tested by the Traveler and a (now super-powered) Wesley Crusher.
- [Strange New Worlds IX](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1416520481) - Q encounters the Pah Wraiths